# Convert MySQL query to MS SQL Server ... failing on aggregate requirements

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

**GOAL:**
I need to retrieve the most recent message date (max), number of rows in its attachment, and the vendors name.
Also, we need to limit the results to messages sent this year (after 2014-01-01 00:00:00.000) which have an attachment with 50k rows or more.

**TRIED:**
See this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bebb0/2).

```
SELECT 
    v.name
    ,a.attachmentRows
    ,MAX(e.createdDate) recentDate
FROM emailMessage e
INNER JOIN vendor v
    ON (e.vendorID = v.vendorID)
INNER JOIN emailAttachment a
    ON (e.emailMessageID = a.emailMessageID)
WHERE e.createdDate > '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000'
AND a.attachmentRows >= 50000
GROUP BY e.vendorID
```

**EXPECTATIONS:**

```
|        NAME | ATTACHMENTROWS |                      RECENTDATE |
|-------------|----------------|---------------------------------|
| "Company C" |         123880 | February, 22 2014 10:00:00+0000 |
```

**PROBLEM:** 
While my SQL skills are rather primitive, I'm fairly comfortable with the MySQL flavor so I started my [fiddling](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bebb0/2) there. That query worked as expected.
When switching over to SQL Server, though, I run into this error for each of the selected fields:

> Column 'blahBlah' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I understand what the error is telling me, but with three tables involved, I'm at a loss as to how to remedy it. (And of course, simply grouping by all the selected fields would not yield the desired results.)

**PLEA:**
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bebb0/8):

```
SELECT 
    v.name
    ,a.attachmentRows
    ,e.createdDate recentDate
FROM emailMessage e
INNER JOIN vendor v
    ON (e.vendorID = v.vendorID)
INNER JOIN emailAttachment a
    ON (e.emailMessageID = a.emailMessageID)
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(emailMessageID) emailMessageID, vendorID from emailMessage group by vendorID) as maxi
    on maxi.emailMessageID = e.emailMessageID
WHERE e.createdDate > '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000'
AND a.attachmentRows >= 50000
```

This assumes the emailMessageID increments with the createdDate.  Using the date is problematic if two emails arrive at the exact same time stamp.

Comment: Ahh .. I see what you did there. While making @$$umptions about the `emailMessageID` incrementation could be dangerous, it works perfectly for this case. Thanks-a-bunch.

Comment: Indeed, it's not a perfect solution.  You may also wish to join the emailAttachment table within the new INNER JOIN I added, and move the >= 50000 predicate into it as well, so you get the max emailMessageID where the row count is over 50K.  Hope it helps get you pointed in the right direction at least.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly the hand-up I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    v.name
    ,a.attachmentRows
    ,MAX(e.createdDate) recentDate
FROM emailMessage e
INNER JOIN vendor v
    ON (e.vendorID = v.vendorID)
INNER JOIN emailAttachment a
    ON (e.emailMessageID = a.emailMessageID)
WHERE e.createdDate > '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000'
AND a.attachmentRows >= 50000
GROUP BY v.name ,a.attachmentRows
```

Comment: This will return multiple records as it is grouped on attachmentRows.

Comment: Grouping by `v.name` can work, but unfortunately grouping by `a.attachmentRows` will prevent us from getting only the latest result for that vendor. Thank you for the suggestion anyhow :)